# Grid Breakpoints not covering width of screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, less, pug

Technologies:

Bootstrap 3
Less
Jade
Angular

Issue:

I'm using .col-xs-12.col-md-6 for the section.

For some reason when it should switch from .col-md-6 and .col-xs-12 should be applied so that the column can stretch the full width of the screen, the layout doesn't spread out until 743 screen width. (It should go full width at 991px or if i'm wrong atleast 767px screen width).

I have custom styling on .col-md-6 and apply 49% to the width of that class bc .col-md-5 was too small and .col-md-6 was too large to add the needed 20px margin space in between. (styling guidelines).

I removed the width: 49%; when seeing what would happen at the 992 and 768 break point and there is nothing.

It just breaks at random breakpoints.

(I've tested where it breaks for col-lg-6 and col-xl-6 or 5 .. just to test it out and it continues to break in break point areas not connected to the usual 768, 992, 1200 etc.)

I have removed styling from every place possible to see if thats effecting it .. 
This is an include file and so even styling connected to the main page. (I put it back bc that wasn't the cause).

These break point additions have worked in the past I don't know whats wrong now.

My only other alternative is using media queries instead which I will try in the meantime but I am wanting to avoid that.

**Update:**

I reformatted the code in an entirely separate file from the project and put it in regular html and it worked fine. I copied and pasted the code at the very bottom. I removed angular and left it hard coded so that i can open in the browser quickly. I am thinking it may have something to do with the surrounding files in this project. I copied and pasted the code at the very bottom.

Jade file:

```
#pizza
    .col-xs-12
        h3 Other Shops
        .col-xs-12.col-md-6(ng-repeat="other in otherShops")
            .col-xs-12(ng-repeat="tag in other.tags | limitTo: 1")
                img(ng-src="{{tag.sm_active_url}}")
                &nbsp;{{tag.name}}
            .col-xs-3
                img(src="http://www.carlotfinance.com/assets/img/car_placeholder.jpg", alt="placeholder image")
            .col-xs-8
                h2
                    a(href="#/shops/{{shop.id}}/detail") {{ other.name }}
                    .glyphicon.glyphicon-road
                    .glyphicon.glyphicon-unchecked
                p {{ other.address }}
                p {{ other.phone }}
            button.btn.col-xs-12.makeAppointmentBtn(type='button', ng-controller='makeAppointmentCtrl', ng-click='open()') Make Appointment
```

Less:

```
#pizza{

h3{
  color: #999;
}

.col-md-6{
background-color: #ffffff;
border-radius: 8px;
margin-bottom: 50px;
padding-left: 0;
padding-right: 0;
// width: 49%;
min-height: 440px;

&:nth-child(even){
  margin-right: 20px;
}

h2{
  a{
  color: #000;
  }
  a:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
  }
}

.col-xs-3{
margin-left: 20px;
margin-top: 30px;

img{
 width: 100%;
}
}

.btn{
 position: absolute;
 background-color: #003366;
 padding: 10px;
 border-radius: 8px;
 color: #fff;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
}

.glyphicon{
  color: #999;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.col-xs-12{
  font-size: 24px;
  margin-top: 20px;

img{
  margin-left: 20px;
}

}
.col-xs-8{
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}
}
}
```

Reformatted code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="full" lang="en">
<head>

<title>Pizza</title>

<!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">



</head>

<body>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 ng-scope">
<div class="col-xs-12">
<img ng-src="https://garageapi.herokuapp.com/tag_tab_icons/Tools/icon-tool-darkblue-25.png" src="https://garageapi.herokuapp.com/tag_tab_icons/Tools/icon-tool-darkblue-25.png">&nbsp;Tools</div><!-- end ngRepeat: tag in other.tags | limitTo: 1 -->
<div class="col-xs-3"><img src="http://www.carlotfinance.com/assets/img/car_placeholder.jpg" alt="placeholder image"></div>
<div class="col-xs-8">
<h2><a href="#/shops//detail" class="ng-binding">Pizza Place</a>
<div class="glyphicon glyphicon-road"></div>
<div class="glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked"></div>
</h2>
<p>1234 M Ave, Austin, TX 27000</p>
<p>(555) 400 2800</p>
</div>
<button type="button"  class="btn col-xs-12 makeAppointmentBtn ng-scope">Make Appointment</button>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 ng-scope">
<div class="col-xs-12">
<img ng-src="https://garageapi.herokuapp.com/tag_tab_icons/Tools/icon-tool-darkblue-25.png" src="https://garageapi.herokuapp.com/tag_tab_icons/Tools/icon-tool-darkblue-25.png">&nbsp;Tools</div><!-- end ngRepeat: tag in other.tags | limitTo: 1 -->
<div class="col-xs-3"><img src="http://www.carlotfinance.com/assets/img/car_placeholder.jpg" alt="placeholder image"></div>
<div class="col-xs-8">
<h2><a href="#/shops//detail" class="ng-binding">Pizza Place</a>
<div class="glyphicon glyphicon-road"></div>
<div class="glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked"></div>
</h2>
<p>1234 M Ave, Austin, TX 27000</p>
<p>(555) 400 2800</p>
</div>
<button type="button"  class="btn col-xs-12 makeAppointmentBtn ng-scope">Make Appointment</button>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Elements of BS column classes [should be put into](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-intro) `.row` and then `.container` elements to behave properly. If they are not the grid is expected to be broken.

Comment: I was thinking this was the issue.. I believe I tried to do it that way...  I will go back and try it again and leave an update. Thank you.

Comment: I just converted it to regular html and tried it out in a different file and it worked fine w/o container and .row. I think it has something to do with the surrounding files.               I left how i reformatted it in the edit above.

Comment: Found out that the guy over the project adjusted the bootstrap settings and that is the reason for the breakpoints not working.